# openmpi-4.1.5 issues witrh finding mpi.h

Tags: linux, openmpi

I'm running kubuntu 22.04 on a framework laptop.

I have just built openmpi-4.1.5, and installed it in /opt. When I run a 'Hello World' program compiling with mpicc, which points to the correct file, I get

mpi_test.c:1:10: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
1 | #include <mpi.h>

. When I issue
mpicc -showme
gcc -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib -lmpi -lopen-rte -lopen-pal -lhwloc -levent_core -levent_pthreads -lm -lz

It doesn't point to the include directory in /opt/openmpi_4.1.5

I have looked at the prior question where it was stated that the problem was surely this error indicates not using the wrappers. I'm using the wrappers, so any further insight would be reallyh appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
The issue was in the LD_LIBRARPY_PATH. Order matters. By putting the nonstandard openmpi installation library first, mpicc finds the correct include files.